# PHP 5.5.12 - Is foreach casting my objects into arrays?

Tags: php, arrays, object, foreach, type-hinting

**Edited for Archival:**

Reading elsewhere online, I was under the impression that you were able to access object properties and array members in a `foreach` loop interchangeably. THIS HOWEVER IS INCORRECT. As mentioned in the comments of my accepted answer, `foreach` does not alter type-hinting or casting in anyway. My issue stemmed from a function passing an array of arrays, instead of an array of objects.

```
$AllMessages = func_getAllMessages($ThreadID);
foreach($AllMessages as $Message) {
  echo $Message->Body; // Error
  echo $Message['Body']; // Works
}
```

Explanation:

`func_getAllMessages()`

A simple function that returns matching data from a database. Upon closer inspection this is where my issue originated from. I was expecting an array of objects, not the array of arrays it was actually providing. If you have similar issues, check this!

In short: `foreach` does not alter casting/type-hinting. If you cannot access data a certain way, check what is PROVIDING data to `foreach` instead.

Comment: what is this ' func_getAllMessages($ThreadID); ' and this ' $AllMessages ' ?  what is var_export( $Message ) say

Comment: *simple function that returns an object populated with message information*: Your error suggests otherwise. A `var_dump($AllMesssages);` will help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert it to an object

```
foreach($AllMessages as $Message) {
    $Message= (object) $Message;
    echo $Message->Body;
}
```

**[See Example 2](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php)**

Comment: I realize you can do this, but that seems a bit superfluous if `foreach` worked as documented, in that using `$var->prop` vs `$var['prop']`.

Comment: `foreach` really has nothing to do with that notation. It will simply return whatever the element is. If the element is of type array like in this case, it is returned that way. If your array was an array of objects then it would give you that `->` notation for objects. This really has nothing to do with foreach

Comment: So perhaps this is an issue within the function returning the values I'm iterating over?

Comment: That is exactly it. Your function is returning an array of arrays, not an array of ojbects. If you add the output of `print_r($AllMessages);` to your question we will get exactly what the issue is.

Comment: I did not believe that was an issue since the documentation advertises that an array can be fed into `foreach` and accessed as an object.

Comment: Can you please refer me to that section of PHP Manual? since i do not believe that is said anywhere over here http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: Ah, I see. The examples were using arrays of objects. So casting isn't actually being changed, but just pointed to, and that what I'm accessing isn't actually casted properly.

Comment: I was mistaken. It was a code example on S:O I was remembering, and not live docs.

Comment: Accepting as answer since you've helped me to see what the issue was and that the behavior was not `foreach`, but the data being fed into it instead. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Cheers. Glad you figured it out